# Conta do Twitter está enviando mensagens sem tradução

Tags: bug, status-pronto, internacionalização

Podemos ver na [conta comunitária do Twitter](https://twitter.com/StackOverflowPT) que o *script* que envia as melhores perguntas e respostas não foi localizado ainda.

Além disto, o endereço lá está `br.stackoverflow.com` ao invés de `pt.stackoveflow.com`.

[image: Captura de Tela]

Comment: +1 Não sabia da existência dessa conta no Twitter @StackOverflowPT